# Checking value exists in an array position

Tags: javascript

I have a large array called "data".

At the 10th array position i have this at its data value:

```
[10] => 1,2
```

Now what im trying to do in JS is something like this:

```
 i = 1;
 if(i in data[10]){
   //great success, very nice!
 }
```

I thought comma separated data might act like an array with the "IN" method, but its not working. I get this error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1' in 1,2
```

What would be the correct solution for my problem ?

Comment: Is the data at position 10 a **string** with the value "1,2", or an **array**, with value [1,2]?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check because i parse it from a PHP file with JSON ENCODE

Comment: @Dave, if you are parsing from JSON then it will be a string. I'll update my example code to show you how to access the individual array elements.

Comment: @Dave, run the entire code example at the end of my answer. It shows how to distinguish between accessing the keys of the array (0 and 1) versus the values.

Comment: @Sim that method is not quite the same because im not looking for the array position they could be in any random position im looking for the value... so assigning them to "valueArray" means i can't call them out as they come.. i have to loop it in a set order =/

Comment: Also i still only get 1 but 2 fails :P

Comment: @Dave, I don't understand your point about assignment to `valueArray` being a problem. It's just example code to show you how to parse a string list into an array and access its values. Can you please state your entire problem?

Comment: @Dave, re: failing on 2, please provide a complete code example from a browser console. [Gists](http://gist.github.com) are great for that.

Comment: @Sim i posted jsfiddle on the other comments

Comment: @Dave, I forked your jsfiddle and added code that shows how to use `indexOf` to get what you need. http://jsfiddle.net/pfFpz/

Comment: @Sim Seems to be the wrong link? That or nothing has changed?

Comment: @Dave, strange. Try this fork instead. http://jsfiddle.net/nRS9m/ The code should show use of `indexOf` inside the `if` statement. The output is very different. The elements at positions in the array are now found. Here is a screenshot from jsfiddle. http://screencast.com/t/wxYy50GpMYj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't show the code for how you assign `1,2` to `data[10]`. The value of `1,2` is simply `2` as you can see from executing the following in a JavaScript shell/console. See the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) for how the comma operator works.

However, the error message you are getting suggests that you have the string`"1,2"`. To turn it into an array, you should use `split()` as in:

```
> data[10] = "1,2"
1,2
> data[10].split(',')
[ "1", "2" ]
```

To iterate over the values you can use the `in` operator on the resulting Array as in:

```
var data = new Array();
data[10] = '1,2';
var valueArray = data[10].split(',');
for (var i in valueArray) {
  alert('valueArray[' + i + '] is ' + valueArray[i]);
}
```

You can run this in a browser console and the `alert` will show you two messages:

- valueArray[0] is 1
- valueArray[1] is 2

Note that you don't need to initialize `i` before the loop begins. The `in`operator will do this automatically. Also, it's good practice to use local variables hence the `var i` in the code above.

On a side note, if you are new to JS but you need to deal with a lot of data structure manipulation, it's worth learning about [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/). Take a look at `_.each()` in particular. Underscore can save you from writing a lot of looping logic.

If, however, you want to do a membership check then you need to use not `in` but `Array.indexOf()`. See  http://jsfiddle.net/nRS9m for an example forked from your jsfiddle in the comments. More examples:

```
> valueArray
[ "1", "2" ]
> valueArray.indexOf("3")
-1
> valueArray.indexOf("1")
0
> valueArray.indexOf("2")
1
> valueArray.indexOf(1)
-1
> valueArray.indexOf((1).toString())
0
```

Comment: The value of 1,2 is not 2. What you are doing on that line is assigning the value 1 to data[10] and then evaluating the value of 2 -- which is obviously 2. If you had checked the output of data[10], you would have gotten 1. I admit though that this is because the code isn't well-formed and the engine does its best to parse it.

Comment: @nbrooks, spot on: the comma operator has lower precedence. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Actually I don't think the , is a javascript _operator_ at all. The output from the javascript console is simply the value returned by the last operation executed. So 1,2 having output 2 is still just returning the value of evaluating 2.

Comment: You could put `1;2` or `undefined,2` it wouldn't matter -- the console would still say 2

Comment: @nbrooks, you are wrong here. Comma is a JS/ECMAScript operator. It's been there since 1.0. See the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). This makes it no different than the comma operator in Ruby and other languages.

Comment: using split does not seem to work, it only finds 1 but doesn't find 2 =/

Comment: @Dave, that's not really possible. `"1,2".split(',')` will return the array `["1","2"]`. Can you show me a complete code example?

Comment: @Sim http://i.imgur.com/4onpX.jpg heres the function along side console log result.

Comment: @sim oh thanks for that, I knew about using it for multiple var declarations but I didn't think it had other significance. It doesn't seem to work quite as expected though because `alert(1,2)` alerts `1` and `console.log(1,2)` logs `1 2`. curious.

Comment: So 1 is a number but 2 is a string.. what O_o otherwise 1 should of failed aswell as 2.

Comment: @Dave, the issue is not numbers vs. strings. It's that the `in` operator traverses the "keys" of the Array and not the values. As you can see in my code above, there is no need to cast anything to string in order to get the values inside the array.

Comment: @Sim Yeh im not looking to use the keys look here: http://jsfiddle.net/WAZmP/14/

I'm looking for the values in the array rather than keys.. =/ but this jsfiddle does the keys only :(

Comment: @Dave, sure. That's why my code shows how to get the values: you need to subscript the array with the key, which is why you need to assign to a local variable, such as `valueArray` first. Without this, you'll have to re-parse every time. What alerts do you get when you run my code?

Comment: @Sim But isn't my jsfiddle create an array of the numbers as keys with the split ? But i don't want the for loop i need to just do a true/false check only.. as i loop the main loop that does i from 0 to 50 etc

Comment: @Dave, got it. You need the `Array.indexOf` method. I'll write an example and post here.

Comment: @Dave, I've updated my answer with how you can use `indexOf` to do an array membership check. Hope this does it for you.